# android studio : emulator not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have AMD Radeon Lenovo and I downloaded android studio the last stable version Iguana . When I launch the emulator, it doesn't start and just keeps loading . I located the emulator in `C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`  and tried to run it from there but nothing happened.

I added the sdk to the path. How should I fix this?

Comment: i found the solution : Create a file under your .android directory called advancedFeatures.ini and add these two variables:

`Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the `C:\` drive storage space; if it is low, then the emulator won't start.

Comment: it's one of many solutions,thanks.